# Is it bad practice to use child object as a parent object attribute in Java?

Tags: java

For example I have a class called entity which looks like

```
public class Entity {
   private User userCreated;
   private Date dateCreated;
   private User userModified;
   private Date dateModified;
}
```

Then I have my User class which is actually a child of Entity

```
public class User extends Entity {
    private String username;
}
```

I have a feeling that there's a loop in the relationship, but object is related in this way in my system, as in all my data is an Entity, and all my entities are created by User, including my User, so my User is an Entity.

I have tested the codes and it works, and my question is, is this design bad? If it's bad is there any better way to implement it?

Comment: This is kind of board, This is based on opinion really.

Comment: Your `Entity` class should not hold any `User` or `Date` objects.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate on [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ArthurAttout when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Indeed, that's not what I wanted OP to do, but I didn't know how to suggest this question be moved somewhere else (maybe it needs some rep I don't have)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing bad about this in general. It's only a bad practice if a base class contains logic that requires knowledge of all of its sub-classes (for example, in order to decide which instance to return in some method call), since that may break the base class (or force it to be updated) any time a new sub-class is introduced.

On the other hand, the JDK itself contains examples of classes that refer to their sub-classes.

For example (perhaps that's a bit of cheating, though), the `Object` class contains references to `String` and `Class`, which are its sub-classes.

If your class relationship requires it, there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently bad about it, in my opinion.

This is really just a slightly modified version of the question "is it okay for an object to contain itself?". The answer is the same in both cases - yes, it is okay.

For example a node in a linked list will contain a reference to the next and previous node, e.g.:

```
class Node
{
    private Node next;
    private Node previous;
}
```

and there's nothing bad about this design.

In your case, `User` *is* an `Entity`, just more specialised. An analogy for the above example might be `Node` and `BranchedNode`.

---

One thing you may want to think about, though, is that if a user requires a user to have created them, which user will create the first user? Kind of a chicken and egg situation. Perhaps the first user will have `userCreated` and `userModified` equal to null? Or maybe they will point to themselves?

Comment: The node is a good example, never thought of that. In my case, I have the first user to have itself as `userCreated` and `userModified` nullable, I was worried the database wouldn't let me use the first user id since the first user is not inserted yet, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

In a general way you don't want bidirectional dependencies and you don't want also that the base class knows its subclasses but only the reverse because all of them may create a strong coupling between classes, that is the changes in any side may have consequences on the both sides.
But it doesn't mean that you don't want ever use this coupling.
Sometimes this coupling is undesirable but sometimes it is desirable and here it  it seems to be a desirable coupling : the parent and the child are semantically very coupled and so it is very few probably that later you want to isolate the User or the Entity to be more independent between them.
So you accept and even want this coupling to avoid duplication/complexity with no value.

Note that you could decouple things by introducing an interface to define an Entity but it is a lot of code to not gain a great thing :

```
public interface EntityAble {
   User getUserCreated();
   Date getDateCreated();
   User getUuserModified();
   Date getDateModified();
  // setters
}
```

to define Entity such as :

```
public class Entity implements EntityAble {
   private User userCreated;
   private Date dateCreated;
   private User userModified;
   private Date dateModified;
   // override getters/setters
}
```

and User as :

```
public class User implements EntityAble {
   private String username;      
   private User userCreated;
   private Date dateCreated;
   private User userModified;
   private Date dateModified;
   // override getters/setters  
}
```

Now Entity is composed of User fields that are not an Entity but a lot of duplication/LOC to not necessarily gain something.
In some use cases this design could make sense but with your actual requirement is sounds an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add abstraction only if it exists in your business domain. Ask following questions - is it a User entity or just a user name (which is just string)? Don't forget about [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle.